# Printing corresponding array index

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

```
int diff = gamesA[0] - gamesB[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < gamesA.length; i++)
    {
        int y = Math.abs(gamesA[i] - gamesB[i]);
        if(y > diff)
        diff = y;
    }
    System.out.println("In quarter finals, largest deficit of schoolB was " 
+ diff + " in the" +_____+ "game.");
```

I'm trying to print out the index in the array where the largest deficit is. Not what the value but the index it is located at. Anything helps."____" is where the needed code needs to be placed.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare variable to store index outside the loop

```
int diff = gamesA[0] - gamesB[0];
int index;
    for(int i = 0; i < gamesA.length; i++)
    {
        int y = Math.abs(gamesA[i] - gamesB[i]);
        if(y > diff)
        diff = y;
        index = i;
    }
    System.out.println("In quarter finals, largest deficit of schoolB was " + diff + " in the" + index + "game.");
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following way:

```
int diff = gamesA[0] - gamesB[0];
int i; // declare it outside the loop to make it available after loop ends.
    for(i = 0; i < gamesA.length; i++)
    {
        int y = Math.abs(gamesA[i] - gamesB[i]);
        if(y > diff)
        diff = y;
    }
    System.out.println("In quarter finals, largest deficit of schoolB was " 
+ diff + " in the" +(i+1)+ "game.");
//i+1 for indexing from 1 onward .. or use just i for indexing 0 onward.
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers so far will always print the last position. Try this:-

```
int diff = gamesA[0] - gamesB[0];
int pos = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < gamesA.length; i++) {
    int y = Math.abs(gamesA[i] - gamesB[i]);
    if (y > diff) {
        diff = y;
        pos = i;
    }
}
System.out.println("In quarter finals, largest deficit of schoolB was "
        + diff + " in the" + pos + "game.");
```